# MasonryJS image gallery aligns left on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

So I have this image gallery which I displayed as Pinterest-style Masonry by using MasonryJS. Everything works fine but the problem is when I refresh the page. That is, when I refresh the page, all the images align to the left at first then comes to the actual place. It's like for a couple of milliseconds it goes to that position and comes back to life.

Here's a gif which shows the actual problem:

[image]

How can I not have it left-aligned in page refresh? I just wish it to stay in the middle no matter how much I refresh the page.

Here's the code:

```js
jQuery(window).on('load', function(){ 
    $('.modal-grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.modal-grid-item',
        gutter: 10,
        isFitWidth: true
    });
});
```

```css
.modal-grid{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.modal-grid-item { 
    width: 300px; margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.modal-grid-item img { 
    width: 100%; height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal-grid">

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m7M9EPX.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NzD7YF9.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8zvUjul.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WNmP9VL.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0nwzhDV.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ypdixv8.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1oHOvK1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kpjtht1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QAQ0dk6.jpg" />
  </div>

    <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m7M9EPX.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NzD7YF9.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8zvUjul.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WNmP9VL.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0nwzhDV.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ypdixv8.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1oHOvK1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kpjtht1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QAQ0dk6.jpg" />
  </div>
  
    <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m7M9EPX.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NzD7YF9.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8zvUjul.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WNmP9VL.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0nwzhDV.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ypdixv8.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1oHOvK1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/kpjtht1.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="modal-grid-item">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QAQ0dk6.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry has [events](https://masonry.desandro.com/events.html) we can take advantage of, like `layoutComplete`. I used that to get masonry to load the images while hidden. Once the `ready` event fires, we trigger Masonry's own `layoutComplete` event to recalculate the elements. Then we run a callback once to reveal Masonry.

```css
.modal-grid {
    opacity: 0; /* jQuery will remove this later */
    transition: opacity; /* optional */
}
```

```js
jQuery(window).on('load', function() { 
    /* Init your grid like normal but save it to a variable */
    const $grid = $('.modal-grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.modal-grid-item',
            gutter: 10,
            isFitWidth: true
        });
    /*
      Add a one time eventListener to just run on our hand-made "onLoad" event
    */
    $grid.one('layoutComplete', function() {
        /* and fade it in */
        $grid.css('opacity', '1');

        /*
        If it is still happening, you can
        add a setTimeout to delay the fade effect
        */
        /**
        let timeoutHandle;
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
            $grid.css('opacity', '1')
            // clear the timeout to make explicitly
            // sure no extra timers are running
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle); 
        }, 1000);
        */
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // trigger the event when the document elements
        // are ready
        $grid.trigger('layoutComplete');
    });
});
```

If you wanna play around with it, you can check out the CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/frankie_tech/pen/WNogBBe).

Comment: It works alright. But the jitter is in the middle now. Your answer is fine. but can you tell me how can I use a spinner/loader while the layout loads ?

Comment: You can try using something like [https://loading.io/css/](https://loading.io/css/), and show/hide it with jQuery. You'd do the same thing as with `$grid.css('opacity', '1')`. Just change the selector and add extra rules to change visibility, see the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/). You would need to figure out the CSS for positioning it inside the masonry container.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works with static data. But if I use dynamic data and fetched with AJAX then the layout is left-aligned. Check this new question I've created. If you have a solution then please do give your thought. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527023/images-align-left-after-using-masonryjs-with-ajax